# Please ask for confirmation when voting on iPhone

Tags: feature-request, voting, user-interface, iphone

It's too easy to mistakenly tap upvote and downvote buttons on the iPhone. I suggest asking for confirmation for any kind of voting action performed on the iPhone's Mobile Safari.

Comment: I think this can be tossed in with http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/896/mobile-iphone-optimized-version-of-so

Comment: Kyle: I intentionally opened this as a separate issue since it's a big thing and probably won't come soon but this issue could be fixed by a couple lines of code.

Comment: Not worth spending time on, IMO, because you can immediately correct the situation if you happen to mistap. (And the rep cap thing mentioned below is too marginal to warrant it.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the answer here is figuring out what the use case is for mobile browsing of this site.  If it's the full experience including answering questions, then I would agree with the arguments that people tend to write long posts, and thus the effectiveness of mobility is less.

My thought is that a mobile version of the site should be created to address this issue. It is mostly a presentation issue, and could easily be developed by the SO team in a reasonably short time period.

However, I don't think the amount of use this would get justifies creating this specialized version.

Comment: agree, this is another request for an API

Answer (score 0):

In a lot of ways I want to agree with this...it can be frustrating...

But on the other hand I have to wonder if this is a case of the solution being too much bother to develop when you could simply say to the iPhone user "Hey...maybe you should zoom in on your screen a bit more to separate the up and down vote arrows."

Comment: It's not a problem of *not being able to work with SO with iPhone*. My issue is specifically accidental downvoting. It did happen to me at different zoom levels and it downvoting a **correct** answer on SO is **really a bad thing**.

Comment: If you downvote a question/answer accidentally, it should not be a problem to take that back immediately once you notice there is a mistake there.

Comment: TheTXI: If the reputation system was implemented correctly, this would be a non-issue (well, at least hurts less) but if either you or the other guy is over his/her rep cap, you and/or him/her will lose reputation.