# A user search option from a mobile phone

Tags: feature-request, search, users, mobile-web

I was showing someone stack overflow a few hours ago from a mobile phone.
Connecting was fine, browsing/asking/answering questions was also seamless.

I did however have an issue searching the user list. When using a 'normal' browser the user search page refreshes as one types in the "Type to find user" textbox. Unfortunately the browser on my nokia did not do this auto refresh.

I realize that most user searches would not be performed on a mobile phone, but would it be reasonable to expect a button to the user search screen to 'submit' a search?

Comment: Yep. Same issue on my Palm TX. If there's no button, you can't submit the search. I would add the tags "mobile" and "BUG" to this question.

Answer (score 1):

Yeah, all the ajaxy stuff doesn't work on Opera Mobile either. That includes voting, closing, etc., and pretty much everything that has to do with comments.

Answer (score 0):

I got it to work in my Nokia 5800 XpressMusic. To submit the search, type your search query and then press 0 twice(which is equivalent to pressing enter key). Now the form will be submitted.