# Stack Overflow optimized for mobile devices

Tags: feature-request, stack-overflow, mobile-web

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Mobile / iPhone Optimized Version of SO](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/896/mobile-iphone-optimized-version-of-so)

When will Stack Overflow be optimized for mobile devices. It will be great to ask and answer questions not just in front of my office machine.

Comment: @Marko, I believe these types of questions and suggestions should be discussed over on http://meta.stackoverflow.com per the FAQ on this site.

Comment: I think he means Joel, not Joe. I suppose he _could be talking to me though :)

Comment: See: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/896/mobile-iphone-optimized-version-of-so

Answer (score 0):

Since the topic has already been brought up, just thought I'd throw out my two cents.

I'd love to see a way to do search, ask, answer and comment by text message.  Maybe with prefixes and various parameters as needed.

Although I do admit, the quality of questions asked or answers may deteriorate quickly.  But thats what the community moderation for is right?

Comment: I'm not cool with this -- texts are what, 160 characters per? I don't see that working to the community's advantage, to be honest.