# Lightweight stackoverflow site

Tags: feature-request, downloads

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Mobile / iPhone Optimized Version of SO](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/896/mobile-iphone-optimized-version-of-so)

Many times I use my mobile phone to browse StackOverflow site. Even with the images turned off each refresh is about 11KB. My operator charges as per the data downloaded. Is it not possible to have a lightweight version of SO site (something like low bandwidth view in MSDN) so that the download is lesser?

Comment: Duplicate - http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/896/mobile-iphone-optimized-version-of-so

Comment: may be..but I am using a Nokia phone with Opera Mini browser, if that matters.

Comment: Why would that matter?

Comment: the linked question looks like about iPhone with Mobile Safari browser.

Comment: To be more specific, iPhone's browser isn't really a *mobile* browser because its browser has WebKit inside it which really is a desktop web browser layout engine core.