# Did you ever wish you could have a Hot Dog Stand-themed meta.stackoverflow.com?

Tags: discussion, design, fun

Are you depressed by all the gr[ae]y colors plaguing meta? Do you wish you had some exuberance on your favorite website? Are you hungry?  Are you still reading this?

Well, worry no longer. I'd like to think I've developed a solution to all of your problems with a user style mimicking the abortion known as the [Hot Dog Stand theme](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2005/07/a-tribute-to-the-windows-31-hot-dog-stand-color-scheme.html) from earlier versions of Windows:

[image: HOT DOG STAND YEAH]

Here is the CSS:

```
@namespace url(http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml);

@-moz-document domain("meta.stackoverflow.com") {

.answer {
background-color: red !important;
}

a {
color: white !important;
}

a:hover {
color: yellow !important;
}

a:visited {
color: white;
}

#hlogo {
background-image: url(http://imgur.com/jFSWg.png) !important;
}

#header #topbar {
background-color: #ee2222 !important;
}

.badgecount {
color: black !important;
}

.bounty-indicator {
background-color: black !important;
color: yellow !important;
border: 1px solid yellow !important;
}

.bounty-indicator-tab {
background-color: #c6c6c6 !important;
margin-top: 1px !important;
}

#tabs a {
color: #848484 !important;
background-color: white !important;
font-family: system !important;
}

input {
border-color: black !important;
}

input[type=button] {
background-color: #c6c6c6 !important;
font-family: system !important;
}

#tabs a:hover {
color: red !important;
}

#tabs a.youarehere {
color: white !important;
background-color: black !important;
border: 1px dotted #c6c6c6 !important;
border-bottom: 1px solid red !important;
}

#hlogo a img{
visibility: hidden;
display: block !important;
}

.tagged-interesting {
background-color: #ff5f5f !important;
}

.relativetime {
color: black !important;
}

body {
background-color: red !important;
color: white !important;
}

.nav a {
background-color: black !important;
}

.votes {
border: 1px solid black !important;
background-color: #C6C6C6 !important;
}

.post-tag {
background-color: black !important;
color: white !important;
border-right: 1px solid black !important;
font-family: system !important;
}

.post-tag:hover {
border-right: 1px solid yellow !important;
border-bottom: 1px solid yellow !important;
color: yellow !important;
}

.question-summary {
border-bottom: 1px dotted black !important;
}    

.views {
color: black !important;
}

.summarycount {
color: black !important;
}

.stats {
background-color: inherit !important;
}

.statsarrow {
visibility: hidden !important;
}

.page-numbers {
color: white !important;
border:1px solid #C6C6C6 !important;
}

.page-numbers.dots {
border:1px solid #C6C6C6 !important;
}

.page-numbers.current {
background-color: black !important;
}

.started img {
border: 1px solid #848484!important;
}

.user-info img {
border: 1px solid #848484!important;
}

.revision-comment {
background-color: #FF5F5F !important;
}

.owner {
background-color: #FF5F5F !important;
}

.required-tag {
border: 2px dotted yellow !important;
}

.required-tag:hover {
border: 2px solid yellow !important;
}

.moderator-tag {
border: 2px solid black !important;
background-color: yellow !important;
color: black !important;
}

.moderator-tag:hover {
border: 2px solid black !important;
background-color: #c6c6c6 !important;
color: black !important;
}

.moderator-tag:visited {
color: black !important;
}

code {
background-color: #ff5f5f !important;
}

.comment-text {
color: white !important;
}

.comment-hover {
background-color: #ff5f5f !important;
}

.comment-hover .owner {
background-color: red !important;
}

#wmd-input {
background-color: black !important;
color: #C0C0C0 !important;
font-family: "courier new" !important;
font-size: 10pt !important;
font-weight: bold !important;
}

#wmd-button-bar {
border: 3px solid black !important;
}

.community-option label {
color: white !important;
}

#wmd-preview {
color: black !important;
background-color: white !important;
border: 3px solid black !important;
}

#wmd-preview a {
border-bottom:1px dotted #c6c6c6 !important;
color:#848484!important;
text-decoration:none !important;
}

#wmd-preview a:hover {
border-bottom:1px dotted #c6c6c6 !important;
color: black !important;
}

.form-submit input {
background-color: #c6c6c6 !important;
font-family: system !important;
font-size: 200% !important;
}

.com {
color: #c6c6c6 !important;
}

.pln { 
background-color: #ff5f5f !important;
}

.module {
border: 2px dotted black !important;
background-color: #ff5f5f !important;
}

#user-about-me {
background-color: #ff5f5f !important;
}

.answer-votes {
border: 1px solid black !important;
background-color: #ff5f5f !important;
}

.answered {
background-color: #00FF00 !important;
color: white !important;
border: 1px solid black !important;
}

.answered-accepted {
background-color: #00FF00 !important;
color: yellow !important;
border: 1px solid black !important;
}

.unanswered { 
background-color: gray !important;
border: 1px solid black !important;
}

.tabs-question-user a.youarehere, .tabs-answer-user a.youarehere, .tabs-favorite-user a.youarehere {
background-color: black !important;
}

.tabs-question-user a.youarehere:hover, .tabs-answer-user a.youarehere:hover, .tabs-favorite-user a.youarehere:hover {
border-color: yellow !important;
}

.date-span {
background-color: #ff5f5f !important;
color: black !important;
border: 1px dashed yellow !important;
}

.date_brick {
background-color: #ff5f5f !important;
color: black !important;
border: 1px solid black !important;
}

.upvote {
background-color: #00FF00 !important;
color: yellow !important;
border: 1px solid black !important;
}

.accept-answer-link {
color:#00FF00 !important;
font-weight:bold;
}

.grpos {
color: #00ff00 !important;
}

blockquote {
background-color: #ff5f5f !important;
}

pre {
background-color: #ff5f5f !important;
}


.question-status {
background-color: #ff5f5f !important;
}

.deleted-answer {
background-color: #ff5f5f !important;
}

/* VALUABLE FLAIR HOTDOG STAND OVERRIDES (doesn't work in all cases) */
.valuable-flair
{
    background-color: #ff0000 !important;
    border-right: 1px solid #000000 !important;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #000000 !important;        
    font-family: Arial, Liberation Sans, DejaVu Sans, sans-serif !important;
    font-size: 12px !important;
    height: 50px !important;
    padding: 3px !important;
    width: 200px !important;
}
.valuable-flair .gravatar
{
    float: left !important;
}
.valuable-flair .gravatar img
{
    width: 50px !important;
    border: 1px solid #ffff00 !important;
    -ms-interpolation-mode: bicubic !important;
}
.valuable-flair .userInfo
{
    float: right !important;
    text-align: right !important;
}

.valuable-flair .userInfo .username
{
    line-height: 12px !important;
}
.valuable-flair .userInfo .username a
{
    font-weight: bold !important;
    text-decoration: none !important;    
    color: #ffff00 !important;
}
.valuable-flair .userInfo .username img
{
    border: none !important;
    padding-right: 3px !important;        
}
.valuable-flair .badge1
{
    color: #ffcc00 !important;
    font-size: 120% !important;
    margin-left: 3px !important;
}
.valuable-flair .badge2
{
    color: #c0c0c0 !important;
    font-size: 120% !important;
    margin-left: 3px !important;
}
.valuable-flair .badge3
{
    color: #CC9966 !important;
    font-size: 120% !important;
    margin-left: 3px !important;
}
.valuable-flair .reputation-score
{
    color: #ffffff !important;
    font-size: 120% !important;
    font-weight: bold !important;
    margin-right: 2px !important;
}
.valuable-flair .badgecount
{
    color: #ffffff !important;
    padding-left: 1px !important;
}
.valuable-flair .mod-flair {
    color:#FFFF00 !important;
    font-size:140% !important;
    font-weight:bold !important;
    margin-left:3px !important;
}

/* END VALUABLE FLAIR OVERRIDES */

}
```

I have not fully tested every aspect of it, but for the most part it seems to work (as well as Hot Dog Stand possibly can work, that is.)

Comment: I *demand* that you change the font to MS Comic Sans!

Comment: **KILL IT! KILL IT WITH FIRE!!**

Comment: You are a sad, strange little man, and you have my pity. +1 for effort though.

Comment: And what about a laser themed version of meta?

Comment: @Paul - that sounds like a one awesome Greasemonkey script that needs to be developed...

Comment: Did anyone else read the title as "Did you ever wish you had a Hot Dog Stand *named* meta.stackoverflow.com?" and wonder what on earth this was about?

Comment: I'll upvote you if you create a ponies and waffles theme.

Comment: *My eyes! Ze goggles, zey do nussing!*

Comment: http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2005/07/a-tribute-to-the-windows-31-hot-dog-stand-color-scheme.html

Comment: this is a good start, but there needs to be a bit more yellow in the design. Can you post at least 2 screenshots? one of home page, the other of an individual question? Both should have more.. yellowness. See the screenshot of the real HDS posted below for comparison.

Comment: @Changeling: the page has been parked, please remove the link :(

Comment: @Double Welbog, looks like it already _has_ been killed with fire.  ...  Mmm, fire-grilled hot dogs.

Comment: Almost better than [the new grey](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/896/mobile-iphone-optimized-version-of-so/50689#50689) for mobile devices. ;-)

Answer (score 95):

**Did you ever wish you could have a Hot Dog Stand themed meta.stackoverflow.com?**

No.

Comment: This is clearly the correct answer.

Answer (score 42):

**AAAAHHHHHH!!!!!**

[image]
<sub>(source: [typepad.com](https://codinghorror.typepad.com/.a/6a0120a85dcdae970b0120a86d4df2970b-pi))</sub>

Comment: Oh God! Nostalgia.

Comment: it's so awesome.

Comment: My eyes are actually physically lighting themselves right now.

Comment: Microsoft Bob!!