# How can I change the default font and color on Stack Overflow?

Tags: support, user-interface, design, fonts

How can I change the default font and color? I can't find the options.

Comment: Close as irrelevant, or migrate to MSO, possibly SU (if edited to how to override CSS in a My-Browser-Of-Choice).

Comment: You should take a look at this: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/34939/did-you-ever-wish-you-could-have-a-hot-dog-stand-themed-meta-stackoverflow-com

Comment: See also: [How to change all fonts on Stack Exchange sites?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/300905/309993)

Comment: Change your OS, apparently.

Answer (score 1):

That setting doesn't exist, you'll have to hack those changes.

Comment: how to???????????

Comment: @Mathsman100, Here is the [link](http://www.greasespot.net/). You'll need to understand web programming to do what you want, and I don't the specifics of how to make those changes.