# How to change all fonts on Stack Exchange sites?

Tags: support, design, fonts

I'm not asking SE to change its fonts. I think people are misreading my post. I just want help on changing fonts on my own PC because I always customise things I use a lot; my car, my phones, my PC and stuff. So this is tagged *support*, not *feature request*. :)

---

I'm not a techie, and I don't know anything significant about coding or editing CSS. But after some googling and tinkering with CSS with the help of [Stylish](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/stylish-custom-themes-for/fjnbnpbmkenffdnngjfgmeleoegfcffe?hl=en), a Chrome extension, I managed to change fonts to a certain extent.

But there are some things I'd like help on:

- I want the fonts of *all* elements except the `monospaced` text to change to what I pick, a font1.
- I want to change the text editor font to a font2.

Currently, I copypasted some stuff from Chrome's "inspect" view into the Stylish editor; and by trial and error, managed to get to this, even though I have no clear idea what each of the items represent:

```
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Libre+Baskerville:400,400i,700&subset=latin-ext');

html, body, div, span, applet, object, iframe, h, h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6, p, blockquote, a, abbr, acronym, address, big, cite, code, del, dfn, em, font, img, ins, kbd, q, s, samp, small, strike, strong, sub, sup, tt, var, b, u, i, center, dl, dt, dd, ol, ul, li, fieldset, form, label, legend, table, caption, tbody, tfoot, thead, tr, th, td, comment, a, question, .question-header, .question-hyperlink, .answer-hyperlink {
    font-family: 'Libre Baskerville',sans-serif;
}
```

But I don't think it works well because, on some sites, I see a different font for comments, or sidebars or for questions, etc. I want to see monospaced as monospaced itself. I want to improve this.

---

See screenshots in my recent questions: [1](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/300226/309993), [2](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/300007/309993). Or a [screenshot of this very question](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RTvVv.png).

Comment: Try removing `code, ` from the line above in your CSS code.

Comment: @Dan okay, so _code_ is the culprit, I see. I just copied them from the inspect view. I don't know what they represent.

Comment: I don't understand what the disagreement is with the question. I would welcome any thoughts or suggestions.

Comment: Libre Baskerville? Liar. We all know you're changing it to Comic Sans. Admit it.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As far as I know, all monospaced text is in `<code>` tags. You can use the [`:not()` pseudo class](https://css-tricks.com/almanac/selectors/n/not/) to target everything except the code tags...

```
:not(code) {
    font-family: 'Libre Baskerville', sans-serif !important;
}
```

This falls down when code is highlighted though. I can't think of an easy way to exclude highlighted code whilst still targeting everything else on the page without getting really specific with what we're targeting.

We can re-set the highlighted code to another monospaced font easily enough though, which is better than nothing...

```
code * {
    font-family: 'My Codez Font`, monospace !important;
}
```

You can select the post editor with its ID...

```
#wmd-input {
    font-family: 'Another Font', sans-serif !important;
}
```

Note, I've also added `!important` to the end of each declaration. That should override any more specific styles that weren't otherwise affected.

So the whole thing looks like:

```
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Libre+Baskerville:400,400i,700&subset=latin-ext');

:not(code) {
    font-family: 'Libre Baskerville', sans-serif !important;
}
code * {
    font-family: 'My Codez Font', monospace !important;
}
#wmd-input {
    font-family: 'Another Font', sans-serif !important;
}
```

(Swap the font names for something real of course)

Comment: Another minor issue: I see some things in the custom font, which I want to remain as monospaced or sans-serif. https://imgur.com/a/w4Zlv How can I update that? Screenshot from SO. https://stackoverflow.com/a/7546655/5832912

Comment: @NVZ that's strange, I see it as monospaced: https://i.stack.imgur.com/OW7OI.png Did you add the `!important` to the `code *` line? Have you got any other custom styles that might be affecting it?

Comment: I have a bunch of extensions and scripts. I'll go home and try something and will report back. Thanks.

Comment: I had other styles in it. Cleared it up. Now it's smooth. Thanks. :)

Comment: Glad you got it sorted

Comment: Another minor point. `#wmd-input` had to be changed to `.wmd-input` for it to work on all sites the same way, in my trials.