# Invisible text for related questions in the sidebar

Tags: bug, design

On the sidebar titled *Related*, the first two entries are invisible. There is a link, but no visible text. Tried visiting the same page on Chrome, Edge, and IE, on my Windows 10 laptop. Same issue remains.

This was noticed when I was checking [my recent question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/300905/309993).

[image: screenshot of invisible text]

Comment: please scroll down on the main page at least to last 5-10 questions before posting a latest bug to see whether someone else posted it or not

Comment: @redhand sure. thanks.

Comment: @redhand I did a preliminary research "invisible text related". Nothing significant turned up.

Comment: the dupe of this, is a dupe of another one and all of them happened in 11 hours. title may be different but it is a latest but. just scroll down on the main page to see whether it is posted before.