# Choose background and text color on SO

Tags: feature-request, design

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Addition of themes for Stack Overflow](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/57792/addition-of-themes-for-stack-overflow)

I have a dark background-light text policy on my computer (reduces headaches and eye problems). Gmail offers some custom style for the inbox. Is it possible to allow SO users to choose between a few styles as well? It would greatly enhance the experience for me personally.

If there's a shortcut to make Firefox do this, that would be nice as well. But I couldn't find a thing yet.

Comment: This is suggested all the time. Just define your own custom CSS file for SO and you can have whatever you want without making Atwood Angel's implement something very complicated that very few people will find useful.

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/57792/addition-of-themes-for-stack-overflow http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/64169/themes-on-stackexchange http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/26128/stackoverflow-themes http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1089/user-specific-css http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/104/heres-a-meta-uservoice-question-can-you-bring-the-color-back/417#417

Comment: @Sid : sorry I missed those ones. Nothing showed up on my search, as I forgot the search term "themes". Question will be deleted, once I can. Regarding the CSS file, I'm not going to write a file for every site I visit either. I'll just visit less, works too. And given the amount of traffic here, it won't hurt the site either.

Answer (score 4):

Would Hot Dog Stand be an option?

[image]

Comment: Hot Dog Stand is *always* an option... a **terrible** one!

Comment: Definitely this. Subtle colors and easy on the eyes -- what's not to like?

Comment: Excuse me, I'll have to go and find a bucket...

Comment: Argh my eyes!!!11!!

Comment: @Joris, just use the screen, someone else already has.

Comment: They should have laws to prohit this.

Comment: -1 for offending my eyes