# Setting for sites to use the design of other existing SE sites

Tags: feature-request, status-declined, profile-page, design

**edit** please let me emphasize that I don't request *additional* themes but merely the ability to apply the already *existing* design of another SE site, e.g. to make [Physics.SE](http://physics.stackexchange.com) look like [Math.SE](http://math.stackexchange.com).

---

I really like the current themes of SOFU, and I love [Jin's gaming.SE retro suggestion [image: alt]](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/982/design-ideas-for-gaming-site-updated-with-screenshot)

but also [Juan's asking for a more modern-game oriented theme](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/982/design-ideas-for-gaming-site-updated-with-screenshot/983#983) sounds plausible. So, what about the possibility to have a per-user setting of which theme to use for which site (maybe throwing in some bonus themes when Jin has the time)?

Comment: thanks @Chris, recently my finger always slips to type `size` instead of `site` - damn you matlab...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You mean [this](https://stackapps.com/questions/2808/stackexchange-theme-switcher)?

It adds a dropdown at the bottom of the page with the themes of all other sites, and once you change it, it saves the selected theme name to a cookie so the theme stays across sessions.

Comment: Yes indeed, thanks :)

Answer (score 8):

While it is a nice thought, I somehow have to disagree. Managing themes and keeping them up-to-date is quite much work, and the more themes the more work it is. Additionally, the community might want to create themes, so you have to provide a basic toolkit and an interface for that. And then you have to keep even the community-themes up-to-date...

I'd agree to such a feature if the SO-Engine would be OpenSource, because it would be highly logical to provide it as customizable as possible, and then you really could place the responsibility into the hands of the Community.

I think client-side solutions are the best ones for this, like [Stylish](http://userstyles.org/) in combination with [Greasemonkey](http://www.greasespot.net/). It's already [easily possible to re-skin](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/34939/did-you-ever-wish-you-could-have-a-hot-dog-stand-themed-meta-stackoverflow-com) the trilogy.

**Edit:** You might also want to look at these three links:

- [GreaseMonkey Script Ideas & Best of StackOverflow GreaseMonkey Implementations](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3687/greasemonkey-script-ideas-best-of-stackoverflow-greasemonkey-implementations)
- [Do you have a userstyle for stackoverflow?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/37570/do-you-have-a-userstyle-for-stackoverflow)
- [Search for StackOverflow at userstyles.org](http://userstyles.org/styles/browse/site/stackoverflow?sort=popularity&sort_direction=desc)

Comment: What @Bobby said. It's a lot of work just to maintain themes. Whenever we add new functionalities to the site, CSS/HTML have to be updated across all sites, and their Metas. We're looking at 24+ new themes to design as of now(48 including Meta sites). I think GreaseMonkey is a great solution for user preference.

Comment: while using stylish is a good idea, not everyone uses a browser that supports it. Also, with SE growing to areas that are attractive not only to those used to installing a new plugin everyday, a server-based solution might help them

Comment: @Tobias Kienzler: My opinion stands as stated. Though, while thinking about your idea, yes, something similar to [Column80](http://www.column80.com/) might work very well.

Answer (score 2):

> We'll put together a user script at http://stackapps.com?tab=scripts  for folks who really want the white layout -- in fact, we can probably put together a de-styler that converts any Stack Exchange design to a fairly minimalistic one for those that prefer it.
>   -- Jeff Atwood♦
>   ([source](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/479/can-we-please-change-the-design-to-black-on-white/488#488))

Also, Moshe has written a [minimalistic SE script](https://stackapps.com/q/2143/2966).