# Should there be a user preference to change the "skin" of a website?

Tags: feature-request, area-51, design

Now that each website is getting its own "skin" as they graduate from the beta I noticed that there are a few that I really hate.

This is probably to be expected since:

- The layout is more or less a subjective thing; when you create enough and have enough users, some users are bound to not like it.
- The layout of area51 websites is probably given less thought than, let's say, stackoverflow's.

For example, one that I personally don't like is [math](https://math.stackexchange.com/); while I don't dislike the way it looks I find it very difficult from a usability point of view.

So why not add an option to revert back to the beta skin? Another good idea would be - in addition to that - to also offer a "generic" skin, maybe based on stackoverflow's.

Comment: If there are real usability problems in the main design, wouldn't it be better to post about that on the site's meta?

Comment: @Roger: what if other people don't agree? Isn't it much much easier to give the users a few optional choices?

Comment: @Kop: If it's a "real" usability concern, it seems better to change the entire design.  I didn't post as an answer, because there are user-specific (for smaller segments of the entire userbase) modifications that could be useful.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Allow individual SE theming settings](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/64697/allow-individual-se-theming-settings), unfortunately [status-declined]. But maybe have a look at [Bobby's answer](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/64697/allow-individual-se-theming-settings/64702#64702) involving some "client-side" solutions

Comment: @Tobias: well, that question asked to create several different custom themes for each website. I simply want generic themes that apply to all websites, so much of the criticism of the answer doesn't apply.

Comment: @Kop: oh, you mean as in e.g. use gaming.SE's theme on math.SE and maybe throwing in some bonus themes? Then +1-ing you of course

Comment: @Tobias: well, I don't know how much sense using gaming's theme on math would make (since it's very specific to gaming), but there are already existing themes that are very "general" and not specific to a certain type of content. Examples are the beta theme, the SO theme, the SU theme, the SF theme. So what I'm trying to say is that I want to be able to choose between the site's theme, and a list of **already currently existing** themes that are not tied to any particular type of content.

Comment: @Kop: yeah, I chose a bad example. but indeed, as long as one only wants to apply the theme of another existing SE site, the answer to my request is invalid since no additional work for Jin were involved. But maybe Stylish or Greasemonkey can do this for you as well