# Request ability to use "standard" (Beta) CSS style on all SE sites

Tags: feature-request, design

With all due respect to the hard work and creativity of Jin and the rest of the SE design team, personally I like the standard Beta site stylesheet a lot better than most other sites'. Some sites are too gaudy, some just harder to read, and some simply clash with personal aesthetic preferences.

As such, I it would be beneficial to have a functionality to allow forcing either a specific site, or ALL sites on the network that I visit, to switch to default Beta stylesheet.

Please note that I'm aware of workarounds, but most of them require special steps to be repeated either on any browser I use (custom Chrome extensions), or -  even worse - steps to take for every time I visit a site (type in some JS on the console) or don't work at all (if I'm on IE). I'd like this to be a feature of the site itself, so once configured it works 100% of time everywhere everytime.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Setting for sites to use the design of other existing SE sites](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/64697/setting-for-sites-to-use-the-design-of-other-existing-se-sites)

Comment: @ShadowWizard - that question is NOT about built in solution, as evidenced by accepted answer that references user scripts - something I'm specifically excluding

Answer (score 4):

Yes, I know, you mentioned that there are workarounds in your question, but for the benefit of future readers, here's one that I just threw together (that you can use as a userscript):

```
$('link[rel="stylesheet"]').attr('href', $('link[rel="stylesheet"]').attr('href').replace(/\w+\/all.css/, 'beta/all.css'));
```

Before:

[image: before]

After:

[image: after]