# Setting to globally disable custom Stack Exchange site themes

Tags: feature-request, user-interface

I prefer uniformity and would rather see all [Stack Exchange sites](https://stackexchange.com/sites) in the default style (generally all major SE sites use their own styles, the sites in beta state can't yet). This doesn't appear to be possible to achieve without creating site-specific network filter rules.

Another large voting-driven website Reddit allows disabling custom "subreddit" (i.e. "sub-site") styles site-wide in account settings — Stack Exchange should consider implementing this option as well.

Comment: [This app](https://stackapps.com/questions/2808/stackexchange-theme-switcher) may help as well as [this](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/64697/setting-for-sites-to-use-the-design-of-other-existing-se-sites) post

Comment: @user198350 beyond beta there nothing else, so the dupe will do

Comment: Keep in mind that I doubt if SO will work with a beta theme.

Comment: @rene: May be true, I assumed that all SE sites have feature-parity. In which ways Stack Overflow differs?

Comment: @user198350 Stack Overflow got a totally diffrent design, e.g. different top bar (and sticky!), different footer, and think even different font. Technically, it's a totally different site, and part of Stack Exchange only officially.