# Celebrating Christmas on Stack Overflow

Tags: discussion, fun

Will the site be celebrating the festive season at all?

Comment: We could have a Christmas tree and a heap of presents: http://xkcd.com/835/ :D

Comment: Does someone want to port cornify to reindeerify?

Comment: If OP was American I'd assume we were being baited into the War on Christmas(TM) ;)

Comment: @Ether I think Yi Jiang does! :-)

Comment: We could always add special holiday hats and crates that you need to pay $2.49 to open.  Oh wait, sorry, that's [Team Fortress 2](http://www.teamfortress.com/).

Comment: It would be a good idea to have a theme/decoration/something based on Christingles theme
https://christmasgenius.com/christingles-service-history-xmas/ as that is what I see the least.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

Introducing the

> ## [StackExchange™ Christmasify™ Decoratingnator™](http://www.jsfiddle.net/yijiang/rrGYW/1/embedded/result/)

<sup>Yes, that is a jsfiddle link - SO won't allow JavaScript in anchors for security reasons.</sup>

Bookmark the link you see, and run the bookmarklet repeatedly. I'll let the results speak for themselves:

[image]

Alternatively, run repeatedly this in your browser's developer tools console:

```
(function(){if(window.merryChristmas){window.merryChristmas.run();}else{var s=document.createElement('script');s.src='http://dl.dropbox.com/u/1722364/Christmas/christmas.js';document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(s);}})();
```

(Wait a second after the first run for the script to load first before Chrismersifying to your heart's content)

As a bonus, here's a userstyle to let all of you enjoy the Christmas spirit all the time without having the click on that bookmarklet all the time: http://userstyles.org/styles/41559

[image]

---

[image]

Now working with chat too!

---

In addition, if you want just the snow, use this script:

```
var s = document.createElement('script');
s.src = 'http://dl.dropbox.com/u/1722364/Christmas/snow-packed.js';
document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(s);
```

---

The script will also run on other websites, though not as nicely. I'll work on the script for a little longer, so things might break occasionally. Any suggestions welcome!

Comment: An eyebreaking work of staggering gaudiness :)

Comment: You are a dangerously insane person :P

Comment: @j_random Customers who enjoyed this userstyle also enjoyed the [Hot Dog Stand Theme](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/34939/150097)

Comment: I want to upvote but this answer is missing a certain something... Could you perhaps do something to the image that might highlight what the script does?

Comment: *Love* the christmas decoration! I need to get me that user style.

Comment: The green/red bar kinda makes me want to cry.

Answer (score 30):

Stack Overflow's web server will be serving additional cookies.

```
Set-Cookie: flavour1="cinnamon";
            expires=Sat, 25-Dec-2010 08:00:00 GMT;
            Max-Age=86400;
            Path=/;
            Version="1"

Set-Cookie: flavour2="chocolate chip";
            expires=Sat, 25-Dec-2010 08:00:00 GMT;
            Max-Age=86400;
            Path=/;
            Version="1"
```

Comment: Only for users who have been good for the whole year, though.

Comment: what counts as being good on Stack Exchange?

Comment: @studiohack You have to ask that on http://meta.santa.northpole.xmas

Comment: @balpha: your dead-end link took me to the middle of nowhere...big white empty space. you sure?

Comment: @studiohack Sounds about right. If you see a little gnome dressed in green with weird shoes trying to feed reindeers: That's Jeff.

Comment: @balpha: I see. good to know.

Comment: I'm not coming unless there's milk too

Comment: @bemace there might be milk using HTML 5 local storage but you'd need a really modern browser for that

Comment: @bemace If someone brings IE6, there'll be milk (albeit, spoiled). http://hothardware.com/News/Microsoft-Likens-Internet-Explorer-6-To-Spoiled-Milk/