# What is your opinion of the new tag "subscribers" tooltip?

Tags: discussion, tooltips

When you hover over a tag for a second, you see a new popup (at least I think it's new, i've never seen it before) that has subscriber information about the tag.

[image]

Personally, I find this highly annoying.  What is your opinion?

EDIT:

Here's what I find annoying.  If you happen to stop your mouse over a tag, then this pops up, and gets in the way of reading the next item.  This is, perhaps, more annoying for me because I tend to use my mouse pointer as a focal point when I read (sort of like some people use their finger under a line of words when they read).

So, this thing pops up for me all the time and i have to move my pointer off to get it to go away.

Comment: You're going to have to include more information on *why* you feel it's hugely annoying, otherwise there really isn't any point to this question

Comment: @Yi Jiang - My question was whether others do as well.  Rather than rant about my reasons, I wanted to see if anyone else had reasons.

Comment: What browser are you using? You have an UI bug right there; "subscribe" and "rss" ought to be in the same line of "0 subscribers"

Comment: Your question just asks whether you're the only one. You're probably  not, but perhaps you should change your question to ask for other people's reasons if that's what you want to know.

Comment: @Greg Hewgill - Modified the title.  Better?

Comment: @radp - Using IE9 beta.

Comment: See also: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/74470/why-are-there-popups-over-tags-in-the-question-page

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The only thing I find annoying about the popup is the unwarranted attention given to the subscribers count. I'd rather have the question count, or a count of people that marked the tag interesting.

Comment: Completely agree - since when does the number email subscribers mean anything? Why would I subscribe by mail anyway, when I visit SO more often than gmail? There used to a popup menu that let you add the tag to your favorites, which much more useful.

Comment: @Kobi: 90% agree -- RSS provides an easier route to seeing new (and updates) Qs over a range of sites, and from stackexchange.com, across SE sites. However agree 100% with this A: count of Qs (and maybe count of Qs in last 48 hours) would be something useful.

Answer (score 7):

It's annoying on the iPhone. When I touch a tag I can't make that awful black rectangle go away.

Comment: You can just reload the page.  But this is 'straight in at no. 1' as the clunkiest part of the SO UI in mobile Safari.

Comment: this is now disabled for all mobile devices that we detect (based on `user-agent` match)

Answer (score 3):

**help us edit this wiki** is visible even when I cannot edit the tag wikis. It's great wikis and FAQs are more visible, but it's annoying when people *want to help*, and reach a page explaining they can't.
Next, while it does make the FAQs visible, it is still difficult for new users to find them, particularity when *asking a question*.

Comment: this is about to undergo some radical changes. (psst.. we're going to allow edits by anonymous users to *everything* .. but they have to go in a review queue)

Answer (score 3):

I like it and find it useful but I would slightly modify it in two factors:

1. **Delay**: it's triggering too fast imho, add some delay.
2. **Color**: black color is not natural in your usual color pattern; polish it a little.

Comment: it's supposed to be a violator http://www.techtransform.com/id425.htm thus the disconnect is intentional

Comment: @Jeff that's interesting

Comment: I also think it's triggering too fast. Having to be careful where I 'stop' my mouse is a bit of a bore.

Answer (score 1):

I don't like the colors.

Specifically, I don't like that the rest of the page isn't *also* light text on a dark background. The tip *taunts me* with a better color scheme.

Comment: If you're looking for a better color scheme, we've [got](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/72674/celebrating-christmas-on-stack-overflow/72984#72984) [you](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/34939/150097) [covered](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/104/can-you-bring-the-color-back-to-meta/417#417)!

Answer (score 0):

This script will do away with the tag popups. It's restored a little peace in my life.

[Hide tag info popup](https://stackapps.com/questions/2129/hide-tag-info-popup)