# Why are there popups over tags in the question page?

Tags: feature-request, tags, user-interface

This is bad ui design. How many times am I going to subscribe to a tag, if ever? Once, twice. The question page is like navigating land mines that explode unwanted information if you are not careful to leave your pointer in a 'safe' position.

*Not moving* the pointer is a not a good way to signal an event. I have to stop moving it a some point and it may have nothing to do with what happens to be over the pointer.

Comment: It would make some sense in the list of interesting tags, where it's a lot more likely that I'd subscribe to some tags.

Comment: See also: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/74404/what-is-your-opinion-of-the-new-tag-subscribers-tooltip

Comment: Yes, the way it triggers on hover makes it very easy to set off accidentally. A few times today I've been scrolling through the page with the scroll wheel and ended up with a pop-over popping over something I was actually reading at the time.

Comment: The design of the popup is so ugly.. It doesn't fit at all into the website

Answer (score 4):

There's a couple reasons. But primarily, to explain "wtf is this tag thing about?"

[image]

beyond that, it also offers easy access to

- the per-tag faq
- the tag wiki
- the top users in that tag

and, it allows you to find the rss feed and **subscribe to new questions in this tag via email**.

(we'll be adding the favorite functionality here soon as well, renaming "interesting" tags to favorite and going with the star metaphor)

Comment: I do not argue that it does not provide useful information - I think it does. I argue that it does so in a way that provides information that is not always wanted and could be presented through other mechanisms.

Comment: Bummed that clicking on a tag no longer takes me to a page from which I can mark it as interesting or ignored.  Can those be added to this popup?

Comment: @Robert, FWIW, clicking "subscribe" here does add the tag to the "interesting" list.

Comment: @Popular-Demand, what about things where I'm interested but not enough to want emails about it?

Comment: I believe I know what Windows is. So what's the use of the large description? If we're not going to remove this "feature" (is it a bug?), could we make a "lite" version without the description?

Answer (score 2):

> Not moving the pointer is a not a good way to signal an event. I have to stop moving it a some point and it may have nothing to do with what happens to be over the pointer.

So much truth!

When moreover the handler for such a non-event takes considerable time to render, results in a black thing which resizes itself in the middle of the drawing process, and provides information I did not request and which simply has been of no interest to me in the, hmmm, 100% of the times it's been presented to me, one has to wonder who thought this was a reasonable design!

Answer (score 2):

Here is [a script](https://stackapps.com/questions/2129/hide-tag-info-popup) to hide the tag info popup.

Comment: problum solvd..