# Dark Theme for Stack Overflow?

Tags: feature-request

This a just a suggestion. . .  The whiteness makes the website so bright it stresses the eyes for users like me. Can we have an option to change to a darker theme?

It's kind of what [Ars Technica](http://arstechnica.com) does

***Option:***

[image]

***Bright:***

[image]

***Dark:***

[image]

I feel this would definitely be a great addition as far as user interface designs go.

EDIT::

I installed this : http://userstyles.org/styles/35345/stackoverflow-dark-w-small-ui-improvements-v2-2

Custom stylesheet for SO. It's dark, but ugly as hell.

Comment: Asked before: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/search?q=themes

Comment: More specifically: [Make a dark theme available for Stack Overflow](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/111399)

Comment: Ahh. Glad to see I'm not the only one interested in this.

Comment: _for users like me_ Is it from some vision impairment that you ask this? (I can imagine).

Comment: @GertArnold No. Possibly a preference, I don't like glaringly bright stuff like the SO background. It's just pure white and stressful on the eyes.

Comment: I can get headaches if there's too much white and the monitor refresh rate slows down enough for me to notice. Not that it would on any good LCD.