# Why not make a dark theme instead of time travel joke

Tags: feature-request, design

A feature that has been requested several times, which has never been attended to, and with no real arguments other than the amount of work. So my question is: 
why instead of working on any kind of theme related we get this awful buggy "time travel" bad joke theme that no one requested?

[Dark Theme for Stack Overflow?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/139665/dark-theme-for-stack-overflow)

[Having a dark theme for Stack Exchange sites](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/111399/having-a-dark-theme-for-stack-exchange-sites)

[Dark Theme for Stack Exchange Sites](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/284737/dark-theme-for-stack-exchange-sites/284738#284738)

https://meta.stackoverflow.com/search?q=themes

Comment: "bad joke"? I like the joke (and I think many people do). I don't think working on dark theme is more important than many other design features - everybody has their own design preferences.

Comment: I also want a dark theme, but I don't think the effort necessary for it is comparable to a temporary joke theme. Not even close.

Comment: Changing a bunch of fonts and colours in the CSS probably takes less time than making sure every part of the website accommodates for the requirement of having light text and dark backgrounds. The dark theme would also have to take site-specific designs into consideration. If you want a dark theme now, there are browser extensions/userscripts that can do the job.

Comment: Agree with @MoonRunestar DarkReader chrome extension for the win. Works great on almost every site on the internet. Also agree with the OP though, it's not even April Fools yet in many places in the world (it's still 31st March in the UK) so getting smashed in the face with this every time I go to SO isn't at all funny, it's just annoying

Comment: This isn't a valid feature request. "Why not make A because B" is just wrong, no matter what A or B are.

Comment: Since they share the same development cost (CSS dev) they do interfere in each other, so think a little more about it @ShadowWizard

Answer (score 6):

The most difficult aspect of having a Dark Theme is that you have to re-evaluate *every* color choice. Every color choice on *every website* (and their meta) individually. Notice that the retro page uses the same primary color scheme as the regular pages. It may use different font choices or whatever, but the colors are all the same.

So the degree of work needed for this joke relative to having a Dark Theme is at least an order of magnitude less.

Comment: Indeed. Even with a relatively "simple" re-theme like the April Fools one, you get some degree of breakage. The "New contributor" text has virtually no contrast against its background. The team probably didn't test the theme on a page having this particular UI element, so it got missed.

Comment: I'll give u a point cuz the darker theme really has an extra degree of work. But that's exactly why they shouldn't be wasting their CSS dev time into temporary jokes.
Anyway, I already expected this kinda response since critic meta posts always end negativated.

Comment: And probably this is the kind of joke that people do gladly on un-paid overtime. Like on a Friday night "hey, let's expend an extra hour to prank the whole Internet? hell yeah!"

Comment: Especially since the nature of the joke basically *exonerates* you from having to put any reasonable design considerations into your colour choices anyway.

Comment: I've personally implemented a dark theme for multiple apps and it isn't that hard... yes, you would have to evaluate every color choice. However, with the user's help in a beta mode or something similar we could very easily get it done.