# Let us choose a different theme for the Android app

Tags: feature-request, android-app

Please provide a setting to select themes and an option for a white-text-over-dark-background (e.g. twilight, monokai) theme for the Android app.

This would make reading the posts much easier on the eyes.

Comment: There's a post requesting the same thing, but on the SO website instead. http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/111399/make-a-dark-theme-available-for-stack-overflow

Comment: Thanks for pointing out that post. But, my query is related to the official Stack Exchange App on Google Play store

Comment: I am fully aware of that, hence mentioning that it was on the SO website instead. If I was unaware, my comment would be a **possible duplicate** which it isn't.

Comment: @Glorfindel Again, I disagree with your edit here.  This feature request is for the Android app, not the iOS app.  If this is filled for the android app, it wouldn't make sense to make this as a dupe of an IOS feature request.

Comment: @Glorfindel the apps are developed independently so it doesn't really make sense to have a FR for both

Comment: I'm glad to see this feature request no later if it's a duplicate! 
I'm sad to see how old it is, knowing that nothing changed!  With my eye disabilities any high contrast theming/design is highly appreciated!

Comment: @MartinLemburg there is no development going on for the apps for some years now. Also no dark mode is planned to ve supported on the website itself, I currently lack the references. But perhaps there is a userscript around somewhere to turn the site into dark mode.

Comment: @Luuklag For Stackoverflow & most other Stackexchange sites on browser, there is a nice dark theme at https://github.com/StylishThemes/StackOverflow-Dark
However, that's not useful for the Stackexchange Android App 

Comment: @programmer if you combine your comment with mine, it would be a perfect answer

Comment: @Luuklag Agreed. I **eagerly** wish Stackexchange App team takes up adding the dark mode to the Google Play app **asap**, since I'm pretty sure more than half the developers, going by popularity of *default dark* bkgd editors like [VS Code](https://code.visualstudio.com/) and [Sublime Text](https://www.sublimetext.com/), would **highly appreciate** this