# Remove the big negative text-indent CSS rule over the logo

Tags: feature-request, design

Stack Overflow (and other sites in Stack Exchange network) often looks blurred with latest Chrome and Dark Reader extension. This is caused by `#hlogo a` element. which has `text-indent: -999999em;`. If the indent is removed, or is not so large (e.g. -99999em) the issue is gone. Please, do not use `text-indent: -999999em;` to help Dark Reader users use Stack Exchange.

Chromium issue:
https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=660310

Some pages to demonstrate the bug (open with Dark Reader enabled):
[D3- multiple onclick events](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19648092/d3-multiple-onclick-events)
[Force SSH to use a specific shell](https://serverfault.com/questions/162018/force-ssh-to-use-a-specific-shell)

[image]

Comment: I'd hesitate to characterize an issue with a personalized CSS a "bug".

Comment: @ale Actually this is a Chrome bug, but affects users who's eyes can't stand blinding white Stack Exchange design. You can call it a "bug" or "feature", but somebody has put that -99999em indent, and anyway this should be fixed.

Comment: See also: [Make a dark theme available for Stack Overflow](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/111399/21960).

Comment: Try removing it (as you can in the developer tools). As you will see, it is there for a reason.

Comment: Can you confirm if this is happening in a *beta* version of Chrome or the current stable version?

Comment: @Oded It seems to happen since Chrome 55, it used to be Canary in October, but now it's a Stable version. I see that this small fix requires too much effort for you, so I can simply add a fix into [Dark Reader config](https://github.com/alexanderby/darkreader/blob/master/src/config/sites_fixes_v2.json) for Stack Exchange domains, but there are at least 7 other extensions, that use filters for creating dark themes (about 1,000,000 users in total) that don't offer per-site fixes.

Comment: @Oded I have fixed it in Dark Reader, I've set up -256em and the blur disappeared https://github.com/alexanderby/darkreader/blob/master/src/config/sites_fixes_v2.json#L153