# Are there any plans to roll out Dark Mode to non-English Stack Overflow sites?

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, design, international-sites, dark-mode

[Dark Mode](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/395949/4751173) has now officially launched on Stack Overflow, and the linked post indicates it will become available for Meta Stack Overflow (when?). It also says other sites in the network probably won't get Dark Mode because of large theme differences. But what about the non-English Stack Overflow sites? They basically use the same theme, the only difference is the colour of the logo. If you can enable Dark Mode [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/), you can do it [here](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/) as well. Are there any plans for this?

(Inspired by [¿Cuándo llega el modo oscuro a Stack Overflow en español?](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/4779/22845) – "When does Dark Mode arrive on Stack Overflow in Spanish?". I'm posting this here since it affects multiple sites in the network.)

Comment: If you start down the Dark Mode path, if you take the quick and easy path, as Catija♦ did, you will become an agent of Stack Exchange.

Comment: @Catija I noticed it too; feel free to post an official answer (or let one of your colleagues do it) and I'll accept that and delete mine.

Comment: Cool.  :) I let Nicolas know.

Comment: @Catija I would like to think this is the easiest hurdle to tackle in the journey towards the entire network supporting dark mode. Are there any, more or less, concrete plans on supporting this on the other sites?

Comment: @Luuklag Not at this point. For designed sites it will be complicated (to greater or lesser extents based on the site - for example, easy on SFF but hard on Cooking). For Beta sites, less so. But, either way, it's not in planning right now.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The feature is now live on the other sites:

- Japanese: [ダークモードが利用可能になりました！](https://ja.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/3426/19769)
- Portuguese: [Tema escuro agora disponível no Stack Overflow em Português!](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8483/57567)
- Russian: [Темный режим доступен на Stack Overflow на русском!](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/10996/223536)
- Spanish: [Modo de noche ya disponible en Stack Overflow en español](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/4906/22845)

It looks like your preference is even automatically synchronized with the English Stack Overflow. Well done!

Comment: You may wish to swap the accepted answer, as the existing one is now outdated.

Comment: @RyanM sure. See the comments; I've left the option open for SE to write an official answer. If they don't, I'll accept my own one, but it doesn't matter for the order of the answers because Aaron's has a higher score.

Comment: The [tag info for “dark-mode”](https://meta.stackexchange.com/edit-tag-wiki/256201) is now outdated. Should questions about existing dark mode (as opposed to planned dark mode on other sites) still only be asked on Meta Stack Overflow? (Also, it feels like it’s against the etiquette to include your user ID in the link in the tag description, but I’m not sure about that.)

Answer (score 11):

We’re currently sorting out theming for enterprise, and teams. By doing so, communities and especially the international ones will get the benefits of switching over to CSS variables. This will enable dark mode.

There is an exploration in pull request form, but quite a few steps to get it to a shippable state.

#### Edit

This is something we’re interested in doing but will need to solve some things technically before we can set it to [status-planned](/questions/tagged/status-planned). I’ve updated it to [status-deferred](/questions/tagged/status-deferred) for now.

Comment: Mildly off-topic. This may jst be me missing something, but how is this croissant emoji related to the idea of a "shippable state"?

Comment: It seems to represent a crescent moon @Jenayah; 'cause it's more visible when it's dark.

Comment: @Jenayah It's a crescent moon emoji. It might be mis-rendering on your system.

Comment: Oooohh.... Occupational hazard of being French xD

Comment: Gracias / спасибо / obrigado / arigato.

Comment: Or hungry. And french

Comment: 

Comment: It’s a moon, ya goobers! Dark modeeeeeeee.