# Why is there no dark mode for the per-site metas of sites with dark modes?

Tags: support, per-site-meta, dark-mode

Recently, dark mode was rolled out for international SO sites: [Are there any plans to roll out Dark Mode to non-English Stack Overflow sites?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/351248/339911) But only for main sites.

What's the reason why dark mode can't be propagated to their per-site metas too?

It's *a bit flashy* when I'm switching between main/meta site in case of using dark mode.

Comment: According to the post, Dark Mode *is* coming to SO Meta... eventually.  Not sure about the international Metas...