# Earned a hat on the wrong site

Tags: bug, dark-mode, winter-bash-2020

The trigger for "Flashlight" is

> Have Dark Mode enabled and visit a page on Stack Overflow in English, Japanese, Portuguese, Russian, or Spanish.

I enabled Dark Mode and visited a few pages on English Stack Overflow, and was awarded Flashlight on Stack Overflow en español.

Answer (score 6):

[Dark Mode is synchronized between sites](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/356112/295232) (that support it). If you enable it on Stack Overflow, that will automatically carry over to Stack Overflow en español. Hence the hat script thinks you're eligible for the badge.

Because the script runs at different times on different sites, you don't get all the badges at once.

Comment: This doesn't explain why I got it on the Spanish site (which I didn't visit) rather than on the English site (which I did).

Comment: @Mark SO in English is huge so the number of people who are queued to get it is bigger. It's just going to take a few extra minutes.

Comment: It seems there is something else odd about the behavior of this hat. I do not normally use Dark Mode, but I turned it on on my Stack Overflow profile in order to earn the hat. I navigated to several questions, interacted with them, interacted with the mod dashboard, interacted with more questions, etc., all for quite some time. I never earned the hat. Waited almost 2 hours, to give time for caching/querying, but still hadn't earned the hat. So, I created an account on Spanish SO and immediately earned the hat there *and* on English SO. It looks like another SO mod had to do the same.