# Recent change in tag-badges style doesn't look good in dark mode?

Tags: discussion, design, tag-badges, dark-mode

I think there's been a recent change to tag-badge styles in dark mode that in my opinion makes those badges look less appealing that they used to. I recall tag-badges used to have a deep dark look to distinguish them.

There's now a border around tag-badges, they look slightly smaller compared to regular badges, and they give the impression of a depressed HTML button.

Shown in screenshot:

[image: image of badges in user profile]

(I don't have a screenshot of how it used to look for comparison, neither could I find one in the dark-mode threads.)

Comment: Might just be me, but it looks ok to me.  But then I don't know how it looked before.

Comment: @Snow I don't mean to be a critic (not complaining either), but the tag-badges carry a some weight and this style makes them lighter by comparison with normal badges. The original [dark-mode anouncement](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/395949) said the badges would be audited later but I think this choice of style diminishes the visual emphasis tag-badges had.

Comment: Stack Overflow duplicate (17 hours ago): [Tag badges have an ugly black rectangle in dark mode](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/404462/3648282)

Comment: @Rob it's not a duplicate, that thread is about Top Tags (completely new) and Gold badge close votes...It doesn't focus on the style of the badge itself, nor on the more prominent 2 Badges sections in the User profile.

Comment: bad_coder, Does your comment refer to the question: "Tag badges have an ugly black rectangle in dark mode"? - 1. You commented there and didn't mention that, 2. they use the term 3 times in their report, 3 the 14K user is correct as is their report and my comment above.

Comment: We can [see in their profile](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JnLHf.png) the what and why they are complaining, and that their image points out the same example.

Comment: @Rob Both cases in the other thread are in different sections (one is completely different and besides the other is hardly visible).

Comment: Since DM is currently for SO only, shouldn't this be on their Meta site?

Comment: @Ollie I think the plan is dark-mode being applied to the remaining sites, I'm not sure about the timeline but starting sometime this year. (I also checked the tags and there's so few Q's atm might as well post here since in the future dark-mode issues will probably become SE wide).

Comment: @bad_coder Do you have a source for that? Last I heard, they aren't even able to contemplate it yet. "creating dark versions of all of our sites, particularly the custom-designed ones, is going to be a huge challenge we’re not able to contemplate at this time" See the last paragraph in this post: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/395949/2518200.

Comment: @KodosJohnson sometime after that post regarding the overhaul style sheet refactoring.(I wasn't able find that particular post it had less visibility.)

Comment: I'm going to agree with Ollie here. Despite any plans to bring dark mode to all other sites, it's still a feature which currently only exists in Stack Overflow.

Comment: @Ollie Dark mode is available on the localized Stack Overflow sites. Thus, this is not specific to a single site.

Comment: @KodosJohnson Dark mode is available on more than one site (i.e. SO and the localized SO sites), so this question is not specific to one site.

Comment: @Makyen I guess that is a fair point, since they really are separate sites with their own metas. Voted to reopen.

Comment: @Mak, The five sites are for different languages but the graphics, except for the FavIcon is the same; therefore they are virtually the same site - that the Q&As are different is irrelevant to the fixes required for Dark Mode. --- This doesn't apply elsewhere because no other two or more sites are virtual copies of each other, requiring a tiny fix-up to accomodate an insignificant difference.

Comment: IMHO it's better to leave all Dark Mode bugs/FRs on Meta Stack Overflow; that's were 95% of them are anyway.

Comment: @Makyen But it's still specific to one domain (excluding the Metas).  Nothing is different except the languages really.  I agree with Glorf - it belongs on Meta SO.

Comment: https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/351262

Comment: @Ollie This question is not specific to one Meta site where the user can go in order to get an answer specific to that site. My understanding is that the intent behind that close reason is that it is to keep issues which are about how one specific site handles interactions (e.g. their rules are wrt. topicality, moderation issues on the site, etc.) on the *only* site where it's relevant. Things relevant to more than one site generally belong here on MSE. That close reason is **really** clear that it's only applicable if the issue applies to *only **one** site*, which isn't the case here.

Comment: @Ollie While I've seen staff migrate these to Meta.SO, since dark mode is offered on the international SO's too, it's not correct that questions about them are only about one specific site, so that close reason doesn't apply to them.