# Greatest Hits definition text should be more visible on all sites where dark mode is enabled

Tags: bug, status-completed, design, dark-mode, greatest-hits

Similar to [this](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/401951/text-your-edit-will-be-placed-in-a-queue-until-it-is-peer-reviewed-in-edit-pos) post, the text:

[image]

On the [`/questions/greatest-hits`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/greatest-hits) page for RU SO, ES SO, and PT SO in Dark Mode is too faint, too silvery.  I'd like that to be changed to something like:

[image]

Or (credit to @vaccinatingarachnid):

[image]

So it's more readable.

Comment: And yes, this is for the localized SO sites and SO main, but there's a conversation below [Recent change in tag-badges style doesn't look good in dark mode?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/359630/recent-change-in-tag-badges-style-doesnt-look-good-in-dark-mode), in which Makyen made some good points, so I decided to post my question here.

Comment: I posted that question after carefully verifying it had not been posted in the original thread [Dark Mode Beta - help us root out low-contrast and un-converted bits](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/395949) - or any other existing thread. I advise against potential duplicate reports because it's a nightmare to verify if they've been reported before or not. (Folks taking care of meta.se would be in for a lot of work.)

Comment: Despite Makyen's comment there, there is still the [moderator's comment](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/359630/recent-change-in-tag-badges-style-doesnt-look-good-in-dark-mode#comment1200439_359630) and [mine](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/359630/recent-change-in-tag-badges-style-doesnt-look-good-in-dark-mode#comment1200412_359630)  - when it's a duplication of a single site [continued]

Comment: (and the feature is only available on the site(s), not elsewhere) then it's [disingenuous](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/disingenuous) to claim it's applicable to multiple sites; and therefore better suited to MSE than MSO. - Voted to migrate.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

With the [recent changes](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/375081/new-post-summary-designs-on-greatest-hits-now-everywhere-else-eventually) to greatest hits, this has been fixed.