# WordPress site icon is not visible in the Hide Communities page, on all sites with Dark Mode enabled

Tags: bug, design, hidden-communities, dark-mode

In the [SO (main and localized) Hide Communities page](https://stackoverflow.com/users/hidecommunities/current), the WordPress Development logo is virtually invisible:

[image]

I would suggest making the icon white, like it is in the upper-left on the [actual site](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com), or light blue like the Windows Phone and Woodworking icons (if you have another idea, comment below).

(See [this](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/360523/greatest-hits-definition-text-should-be-more-visible-on-all-sites-where-dark-mod#comment1203069_360523) comment for more on DM reports on MSE)

Comment: It could stay the same color if it had a white border. This way the same icon can be used anywhere, and nobody notices a change.

Comment: @Laurel You still can't see the logo if you just put a border on it though. Then it's just a black box with a white outline.

Comment: @Laurel Wait, I'm sorry, you meant the W itself should have a white outline, right?

Comment: @BSMP Yeah, around the letter, a white stroke as it's sometimes called.