# Was hyperlink blue removed and font weight changed in top-bar review queue links for main sites in dark theme?

Tags: support, status-deferred, design, top-bar, dark-mode

I noticed today that on the main site Dark Theme removed hyperlink blue and the font weights were also changed.

This is currently not consistent with

- Font weights on other sites
- How hyperlinks are blue in other site areas

Was this change done on purpose? It seems to integrate well with the overall theme, but doesn't the lack of blue raise some accessibility/usability issues?

[image]

Firefox 90.0 on Windows 10. SO rev 2021.7.23.39827 and MSE rev 2021.7.23.39827.

Rob also contributed this image MSE: rev 2021.7.23.39827 and SO: rev 2021.7.23.39827

[image: second image]

Comment: Dark mode is only available in Stack Overflow so I imagine this question should be asked on [its meta](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/) instead of here.

Comment: @RobertLongson there was previously a long discussion about that involving several moderators [see the comments under this thread](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/359630). SE has announced plans to bring Dark Mode to other sites on the network, hence questions pertaining to Dark Mode are on-topic on MSE.

Comment: @RobertLongson Dark mode is also active on the international SO sites, and so therefore this question is not only applicable to *one* specific site.

Comment: Probably related to the work done last week that turned sites orange.

Comment: @Catija this one was actually reverted (the links are now blue again like before) and could be marked status-completed. Maybe one of the devs responsible would like to post a brief answer?

Comment: Not yet. While the links are blue again, the "all queues" link is not blue (as opposed to the screenshot in dark mode you've included): https://i.stack.imgur.com/7WaAW.png