# Difference in display between visited and non-visited links in review menu

Tags: bug, stack-overflow, design, review

On all Stack Overflow sites (English and non-English), there is a difference between how links are displayed in the review menu in the navigation bar, depending on whether you visited them or not.

On Stack Overflow, I've visited the most queues apart from the Reopen votes queue (in this browser), and the Reopen votes link is bolder than the others:

[image]

Here's another example from the Portuguese site:

[image]

This does not happen for non-Stack Overflow sites or other menus in the navigation bar, so I guess it's a bug.

Comment: Related [Was hyperlink blue removed and font weight changed in top-bar review queue links for main sites in dark theme?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/367791)