# Color mismatch in achievements dialogue links

Tags: bug, design, achievements-dialog, dark-mode

I noticed privileges and badges links currently have different colors in the achievements dialogue using dark theme.

[image: top "privileges" link is a dark grey and lower "privileges" link is blue; the "badges" link next to each is blue]

Using Windows 10, Firefox 91.0.2 (64-bit), 1920x1080, rev 2021.9.2.40142.

Comment: Click on the tag for [tag:dark-mode]: "Dark Mode is a pathway to many UI elements that some would consider unnatural. Dark Mode is currently only supported on Stack Overflow (English as well as the other languages) and **questions about it should be asked on the site's own meta or on Meta Stack Overflow**. Questions about the possibility, feasibility, or schedule of rolling out Dark Mode elsewhere on the network are acceptable here."

Comment: @Rob ok good link and quote. The tag wiki was last edited by Glorfinel on Nov 12 '20. Afterwards on Jan 15 '21 there was a lengthy discussion involving close/reopen votes on [this thread](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/359630) where several mods weighed in. The consensus was reached that dark theme posts are on-topic on SE. So the tag-wiki needs updating.

Comment: That  was not, and is not, "the consensus".

Comment: @Rob I would say it is because no further objections were raised by the MSE mods. The discussion linked in the comments was thorough and hasn't been overruled in any way since.

Comment: No repro, same build and setup.

Comment: `"I would say it is because no further objections were raised by the MSE mod`**`s`**`. The discussion linked in the comments was thorough and hasn't been overruled in any way since."` – 
[bad_coder](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/369460/color-mismatch-in-achievements-dialogue-links#comment1232869_369460) - There was [only **one** MSE mod who commented](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/359630/recent-change-in-tag-badges-style-doesnt-look-good-in-dark-mode#comment1200439_359630), against it. --- It's not "overruled" because it was never a rule: [continued]

Comment: https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/345762/282094 https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/359923/282094 https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/351262/282094

Comment: I wasn't a moderator back then. I've updated the tag wiki now to say "they're better off asked on MSO". I'll ping staff to ask them what their opinion is on this matter.

Comment: @Glorfindel see [Makyen's comment](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/359630/recent-change-in-tag-badges-style-doesnt-look-good-in-dark-mode#comment1200447_359630). It seems to best reflect usual MSE rules, ruling otherwise would be an anti-pattern exception.

Comment: I read that. Still, that doesn't help if the responsible developers only monitor the [dark-mode] tag on Meta.SO. I don't mind migrating a few questions now and then. And Meta itself is one big anti-pattern :)

Comment: [I actually get the opposite colors](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cYfoE.png) on dark mode myself, is this a "visited link" color thing maybe?