# Plans for dark mode for all Stack Exchange sites

Tags: discussion, design, dark-mode

A while ago, a dark mode was added to Stack Overflow *(including the English site and non-English sites)*. I'm wondering if the dark mode will be coming to other Stack Exchange sites, including all meta sites.

> **Disclaimer:** This question continues on these:
>
> 1. [Dark Mode for Stack Exchange sites](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/111399/dark-mode-for-stack-exchange-sites)
> 2. [Are there any plans to roll out Dark Mode to non-English Stack Overflow sites?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/351248/are-there-any-plans-to-roll-out-dark-mode-to-non-english-stack-overflow-sites)
> 3. [Dark Mode Beta - help us root out low-contrast and un-converted bits](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/395949/dark-mode-beta-help-us-root-out-low-contrast-and-un-converted-bits)

Comment: Eventually.‎​‎​‎​‎​‎​‎​‎​‎​‎​‎​‎​‎​‎​‎​‎​‎

Comment: @Ollie 6-8 eventuallies?

Comment: This is all [tag:status-deferred], eventually, etc. etc.  SO Meta (and the localized sites' Metas) don't have DM yet, so I think that's even farther away.  The devs probably (and understandably) don't want to rewrite the style sheet for all those sites, so I'll hazard a guess at late this/early next year.

Comment: Speaking of which, I [asked](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/404540/when-does-dark-mode-come-to-meta-stack-overflow) about that.

Comment: @Ollie other than MSO (and the international MSOs), I don't think there's any plan to do this and, even if we did, many sites would never get it. Just look at some of the site designs and try to figure out how we'd even make them look good without having to start from scratch... say, cooking or Worldbuilding.

Comment: @Catija One solution I thought of is to implement dark mode for the beta theme. Then if someone wanted to enable dark mode on a site with a custom theme, switch it to the beta theme with dark mode. I think people who would want dark mode in other sites wouldn't mind having the generic beta theme. Do you think that could work?

Comment: @KodosJohnson that's... essentially something I've posted somewhere (that betas would be more likely to get it first) and I've even thrown around the idea of letting people using the plain dark theme... but it's all pretty nebulous right now. We don't have a dev focused on site theming and we're shorthanded as it is. It's just not a priority, unfortunately.

Answer (score 6):

> I'm wondering if the dark mode will be coming to other Stack Exchange sites, including all meta sites.

Sadly, the answer is either ["No" or "Maybe"](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/395949/dark-mode-beta-help-us-root-out-low-contrast-and-un-converted-bits):

> At this point, the focus of Dark Mode is on Stack Overflow and we’ll eventually bring it to MSO. While the retheming we did across the network two years ago makes updating our LESS easier, creating dark versions of all of our sites, particularly the custom-designed ones, is going to be a huge challenge we’re not able to contemplate at this time.

To me it looks pretty unlikely because every graduated site has its own design elements/stylesheets that may not go too well with one DM for all the sites.  As for the Metas, it does say they'll eventually bring it to Meta Stack Overflow (I asked [when](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/404540/when-does-dark-mode-come-to-meta-stack-overflow)), but not MSE.

I do agree with [Catija](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/359739/plans-for-dark-mode-for-all-stack-exchange-sites#comment1200649_359739) - Seasoned Advice *might* not look too good with a universal Dark Mode, but even so, I'd rather see light on dark any day.  I guess we'll have to wait and see...

Comment: Has to be the most boring product development example of the past decade

Comment: That's kind of sad... I was really looking forward to this happening on other sites.