# Add dark theme to Winter Bash

Tags: feature-request, winter-bash, dark-mode

I was going to https://winterbash2020.stackexchange.com/ when the internet got cut. I decided to play the dino game when at around 700, the dark theme appeared. Then I decided to ask this question. Can we add a Dark theme to Winter Bash 2021?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Given that Dark Mode is supported on a very few select sites (Stack Overflow and its non-English counterparts) and the company doesn't make [any promises at all to roll it out to other sites](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/359739/plans-for-dark-mode-for-all-stack-exchange-sites#comment1200651_359739), a feature like Winter Bash, which in 2019 even got reduced development time ([all hats were reruns](https://stackoverflow.blog/2019/12/09/tis-the-season-for-hats-join-us-for-winter-bash-2019/)), is even less likely to get <s>Winter Mode</s> Dark Mode support. So I'm pretty sure this will be [status-declined](/questions/tagged/status-declined).

Comment: 2019 used old hat svgs, but did have a number of new hat definitions. I also upgraded the knitting pallette, and the backend was upgraded to netcore. I worked on it for weeks. So I disagree with the assertion that "there was no development at all".

Comment: @YaakovEllis thanks, good to have first-hand information on this; that was the impression to (at least some members of) the community. I hope the current wording is better.

Comment: @YaakovEllis shouldn't you be on a sabbatical?