# I earned 2cool4skool on a site I have not visited

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, winter-bash, dark-mode, winter-bash-2022

On stackoverflow.com, I went into dark-mode in chase of the [2cool4skool](https://winterbash2022.stackexchange.com/2cool4skool) hat. I didn't get it there, but I did on pt.stackoverflow.
com, which I have not visited prior to getting this hat.

Seems to be a bug, hopefully not applying for other hats too.

Answer (score 10):

It's not a bug, it's a [feature](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/356112/295232). Activating Dark Mode on the English Stack Overflow site automatically activated it on the other Stack Overflow sites as well. Hats (like badges) are awarded at semi-random times, that's why you got it on Portuguese Stack Overflow first.

Comment: It's worth reiterating that Dark Mode is only available on SO (in English, as well as the international SO sites) right now.

Comment: (Also, I believe the processes that grant hats are only run every so often, if you haven't received a hat on one site right after meeting the trigger, give it a few minutes.)

Comment: Dark Mode being SO only is already mentioned in the hat description (which the OP linked to), so that would IMHO feel kinda superfluous. Same as the hat granting process, that is in the FAQ. Of course, I don't know how obvious/discoverable this is to new users here ...

Comment: Still sad that Dark mode is still not available stack wide, same as the last summer bash