# A post is not rendering properly

Tags: bug, specific-question, ignored-tags, rendering

I don't have the knowledge to use the correct terminology, but the post [I earned 2cool4skool on a site I have not visited](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/384717/906208) is greyed out on the "home" and "questions" pages with what looks like some sort of error symbol on the [status-bydesign](/questions/tagged/status-bydesign) tag.

[image]

When I open it, the tags are normal.

It does have a pending edit, but not sure if it's related.

Galaxy XCover Pro, Android version 12, in both "full site" and "mobile" views and using Google Chrome app version 107.0.5304.91.

Comment: I _think_ the crossed out eye icon means it is a tag you've ignored, although I could be wrong. See also [this other MSE post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/382047/my-brain-cannot-ignore-the-ignored-questions-due-to-contrast-change-please-chan)

Comment: @Rick FYI, this [answer](/a/321052) may be of use.

Comment: @cocomac: "I think the crossed out eye icon means it is a tag you've ignored" – Correct.

Comment: Thanks everyone - all sorted. Maybe there should be a hat for "fat thumbs and small screens" @V2Blast

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That's what an ignored tag looks like when you choose "Gray out questions in your ignored tags" when editing your ignored tags list.

I've gone ahead and ignored the [bug](/questions/tagged/bug) tag and had a look at this post from the /questions page. Here's how it looks:

[image: Visualization of this question when the related bug tag is chosen as an ignored tag]

That little eye with a cross through it indicates that it's one of your ignored tags.

If you'd rather completely hide such questions, you can choose the  "Hide questions in your ignored tags" option when editing your ignored tags:

[image: Ignored tags display, with options visible for hiding/graying out]

Comment: OK, thanks. I didn't know I ignored anything! Just got to work out to un-ingnore!!

Comment: @Rick: You can watch/unwatch or ignore/unignore a tag either from (a) the "Watched Tags"/"Ignored Tags" boxes in the right sidebar on the home page of the site, (b) the [Tag watching and ignoring](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/tag-notifications/current) page of your user settings, or (c) the popover that appears when you hover over the specific tag.