# Are Themes only available on Stack Overflow?

Tags: support

On Stack Overflow I set a dark theme because I find that much more convenient. Now I wanted to change that bright theme on other sites as well, but there is no such option.

Is this a thing, only available for Stack Overflow or maybe reputation dependent?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Dark Mode for Stack Exchange sites](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/111399/dark-mode-for-stack-exchange-sites)

Comment: [This answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/345762/377214) to that question addresses your question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Dark mode is only available on Stack Overflow and Stack Overflow for teams. See this [post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/111399/dark-mode-for-stack-exchange-sites) for more info.