# What are some examples of major changes that came from peoples' posted suggestions on this site?

Tags: support, stack-exchange, meta

I understand that on this site it's possible to make suggestions for changes to the network.  If this is an effective way of getting changes made to the network, then surely there must be some instances where someone posted a suggestion that resulted in some change - whether it be a feature change, a new Stack Exchange site, a policy change, or something else.

What are some examples of instances where a change to the network came about from a person making a suggestion in the meta site?  Are there instances, in which someone made a suggestion that was turned down, and another person made the same suggestion and got it implemented?

Comment: Please read the description of the [[tag:status-completed]] tag.

Comment: Even more precise: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/status-completed+feature-request

Comment: Here is a SEDE query for status-completed feature-requests that are linked to a status-declined one: https://data.stackexchange.com/meta.stackexchange/query/1441863

Comment: How do you define "major change"? E.g., would [dark mode](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/111399/dark-mode-for-stack-exchange-sites) count? (It was implemented [6-8 years](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19478/the-many-memes-of-meta/19514#19514) later.)

Comment: Related: [Have a list somewhere of features changed or implemented](/q/18355/289905).