# Dark mode is out of beta and 2020-2022 had hats for trying it out, but it still isn't expanded to other sites. Why?

Tags: discussion, design, dark-mode

The [blog post announcing dark mode](https://stackoverflow.blog/2020/03/30/introducing-dark-mode-for-stack-overflow/) now reports that dark mode is:

> officially out of beta!

Along the way, we got a lot of pretty hats referencing the feature:

| 2022 | 2021 | 2020 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2cool4skool | Glare Reducers | Flashlight |
| [image: 2cool4skool hat] | [image: Glare Reducers hat] | [image: Flashlight hat] |

Is there some technical difficulty preventing it from being expanded to other sites?
Does the fact that many of Stack Exchange's other sites have custom color combinations present an issue for dark mode?

Comment: This answer to [Dark Mode for Stack Exchange sites](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/111399/dark-mode-for-stack-exchange-sites) addresses why: https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/345762/377214

Comment: *The artwork on some of those sites simply can’t be made dark because we don’t have access to the original art files* means quite a bit. Most of Stack Exchange's original designers don't work for SE anymore (or were simply contractors) and trying to get the original asset files from them would be a tall order.

Comment: Nearly every site's on a new design or a refurbished one. I suspect its more a matter of whether there's the resources to do it than anything else.