# Font adjustment for certain parts of Stack Overflow

Tags: support, stack-overflow, code-block, fonts

The Consolas font, which the CSS sets as the preferred font for the code blocks on Stack Overflow, looks exceedingly terrible on my machine (it's my favourite font on Windows, but on Linux... blech).

It would be really helpful (to me anyway) if somewhere on the site I could change the font for code blocks, so that the font I specified would become the preferred font for code blocks. My eyes would be grateful.

Comment: What about [this](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/34939/did-you-ever-wish-you-could-have-a-hot-dog-stand-themed-meta-stackoverflow-com)? ;-)

Comment: @ShadowWizard I don't exactly want a hot-dog themed meta, but if you take away everything but the font specification, it looks like the right thing. How do you use it?

Comment: Not sure, never done that myself but [this](http://webdesign.about.com/od/css/ht/htcssuserfirefo.htm) look promising. :)

Comment: @ShadowWizard oh, I use Chrome :)

Comment: [Stylish for Chrome](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/fjnbnpbmkenffdnngjfgmeleoegfcffe) or put the CSS in your Default/User Stylesheets/Custom.css file @SethCarnegie.

Comment: @Mat that's exactly what I was looking for. If you want to add that as an answer I'll upvote and accept.

Comment: @SethCarnegie: You might also want to check out [superuser](http://superuser.com/) and/or [Unix & Linux](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) to get your font fixed :)

Comment: @Mat nah, I've already gotten used to Droid Sans Mono. I know what the problem is though, but I can't fix it because of a series of unfortunate dependencies. Thanks again.

Comment: If Consolas is that ugly, why not remove it entirely? Like on these sites the CSS will then fall back to the next from the list: `font-family: Consolas, Menlo, Monaco, Lucida Console, Liberation Mono, DejaVu Sans Mono, Bitstream Vera Sans Mono, Courier New, monospace, serif`. Not your first choice indeed, so the user stylesheet is a better fix. But other sites will probably have similar fallbacks defined.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

All you need for that is a user stylesheet with something like the following:

```
#mainbar code {
    font-family: Serif !important;
}
```

Serif *might* not be the best selection here :). The `#mainbar` selector should make it match all over SE, and hopefully not too much elsewhere.

For Chrome, you need to put that in your `Default/User Stylesheets/Custom.css` file. (Not sure where that lives on Windows. On Linux, should be under `~/.config/chrome`.)

Given that most modern browsers let you have user stylesheets, and that extensions for doing things like this exist (like http://userstyles.org for instance, with [Stylish for Chrome](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/fjnbnpbmkenffdnngjfgmeleoegfcffe), plugin also exists for Firefox), I don't think there is enough justification to having per-user settings for this.

If you give the option just for the code-block font, someone's going to ask for some other font tunable, or color, or spacing, or... and that's probably going to end up being a QA nightmare.

Comment: Brilliant, thanks. FWIW, it's Droid Sans Mono :)

Comment: So, @Seth, is this still a feature request? If not, please retag it as support.