# If there are hats why not goggles, or ties or t-shirts?

Tags: discussion, feature-request, status-declined, winter-bash-2013

There are newly added Hats on StackExchange

and that's only for fun

are they going to add **Goggles**, **Tie**, or **funny T-shirts** too 
and what about **moustache**

is SO going to be more funny or coloured in next few months.

as the bar changed, the Hats and what the next??

Comment: But then Meta would be over-run with more complaints/questions about goggles, ties and t-shirts.

Comment: yeah thats the point there will be more rush on that case

Comment: Because, hats keep the brain worm.

Comment: There's definitely Scuba goggles.

Comment: [Epaulettes!](http://meta.cstheory.stackexchange.com/questions/2738/should-we-participate-in-the-stack-exchange-winter-bash/2744#2744) (I think SHRUG was slightly ahead of YES on the cutoff date.)

Comment: [Ask and ye shall receive](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/34939/did-you-ever-wish-you-could-have-a-hot-dog-stand-themed-meta-stackoverflow-com)

Answer (score 14):

But there *is* a tie. It's the one Aretha Franklin [wore on her head](http://www.npr.org/2013/01/21/169731646/aretha-franklin-was-already-famous-but-her-hat-maker-wasnt) at the presidential inauguration a while back:

[image: Tiny Tim Tie]

<sup>(This is "Tiny" Tim Post, our bowtie-loving community manager)</sup>

There are goggles too. You just have to be similarly creative...

Comment: You look a little... *lost* under there, Shog9!

Comment: Indeed, I look like [an absolute idiot](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Y8K1fTZaR7w)

Answer (score 9):

A "hat" is a loosely defined term for any of a number of items you can wear on your avatar. They are certainly not just hats.

Currently, [what you see is what you get](http://winterbash2013.stackexchange.com) in terms of hats (though there are a few secret ones to be discovered!). Winter Bash only lasts a few weeks, so in early January, the hats (and accessories) will go away. Assuming we re-run the event next year, there will be all new hats (or goggles, or ties, or funny t-shirts, or moustaches) to sport.

Comment: This is the next year and we now even have callboxes. So there is that.