# Why does this question show 2 different close reasons?

Tags: support, vote-to-close, close-reasons, custom-close-reasons

I just found [this closed question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/34939/did-you-ever-wish-you-could-have-a-hot-dog-stand-themed-meta-stackoverflow-com). The banner saying it was closed shows 2 different reasons and who voted for each reason.

[image]

I've never seen this before. From what I've read, only the close reason with the most close votes gets shown. The "pertains only to a specific site" close reason had the most votes, yet both of them were still shown.

How and why did this happen?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

When a question is closed as off-topic, all of the canonical (non-custom) sub-reasons which accumulated at least 2 votes or a diamond vote are shown as guidance for why the question was deemed off-topic. This effectively allows for up to two sub-reasons to appear, with a diamond as the fifth vote allowing a third sub-reason to appear (assuming a 2+2+diamond split).