# Request for Comments: StackOverflow Mobile Site

Tags: discussion, mobile-web

**UPDATE:** The site is live and has quite a few features already: http://m.stackoverflow.quickmediasolutions.com/

Please let me know what you think.

---

The number of upvotes on [this](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/896/mobile-iphone-optimized-version-of-so) post have made me realize just *how many people want an iPhone/mobile version of StackOverflow*!

So, now that the API is in private beta, there is the possibility for someone to make a front-end for StackOverflow that is optimized for mobile-devices.

I am considering undertaking this, but I will need your advice:

- Do you want just a low-fi HTML version, or a WAP/WML version? (Of course, we will need an HTML version if iPhones are going to be supported.)
- What functionality do you want exposed?

I want to make one thing clear: **this site will be read-only!** *You will not be able to post/comment/vote or anything like that.* This is because the API is currently read-only.

Your opinion is valuable, so please comment/answer this question.

The benefits of this site:

- Extremely small pages: average is maybe ~4KB a page.
- Light on graphics: the only image is the logo which is ~2KB and is cached automatically
  **Note:** actually that's not quite true - viewing a user's profile brings in images from Gravatar :)
- Fast: pages are served as fast as the SO API serves the data to me

Comment: Stackoverflow already works read-only on my phone, so kinda pointless. What doesn't work is things like comments and voting. I believe you can even get notifications, give answers, and even cast close votes and make edits. That said I don't browse it on my phone very often though

Comment: @Earlz: On my [phone](http://www.prowireless.ca/phones/pcs/lg_285_handset_open_lg_s.gif), I can do everything - well, except the stuff that broke with the recent accessibility updates.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Honestly, a read-only mobile site to me would be kinda useless.  I'd want the interaction on my phone.  A read-only site would make more sense to me where I'm sitting at my dev tools pondering a problem and looking for a solution and that's at my PC, not my phone.

**EDIT:**
Ok, since the read/write is because of the status of the API right now then go nuts.  Just sounded like you were in the market to make a (useless) read/write mobile site.

I want whatever works for my new Incredible that just got ordered today!  Just breaking into the mobile market, so whatever that means.

On a mobile site I'd like to see

- Ask questions
- Answer questions
- Comments
- Voting (all posts, comments)

Comment: Well don't look at me... I'm not making the API.

Comment: But you *are* making the read-only site...

Comment: It's read-only because the API Jeff & Co. are making is read-only.

Comment: +1; SO is fundamentally participatory and participation means interaction.

Comment: Boy, it's not like it's my fault it's this way! Go complain to Jeff if this bothers you so much! Actually, don't. Jeff is too nice to deserve that kind of complaining.

Comment: @George: see my edit.  I'd say reword your question to make it clear that the read-only is because the API is read-only.

Comment: @squill: Fixed.