# mobile version? Cellular version?

Tags: feature-request, mobile-web

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Mobile / iPhone Optimized Version of SO](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/896/mobile-iphone-optimized-version-of-so)

Does SO have a cellular, or "mobile" version? One with much smaller graphics/text and more adapted to small screens?

I just visited this site from my Nokia E65 and noticed that I was served the regular version.

Are you planning on such kind of thing?

Comment: If read-only is okay for you, take a look at http://stackapps.com/questions/36/stackmobile-stackoverflow-for-mobile-phones

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/896/mobile-iphone-optimized-version-of-so Discusses your request.

Answer (score 1):

For the foreseeable future, this issue is likely to be handled through 3rd party applications rather than through custom CSS or other types of custom server-side work.

[Mobile / iPhone Optimized Version of SO](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/896/mobile-iphone-optimized-version-of-so)