# Stackoverflow iPhone App

Tags: support, stack-overflow, iphone

When is there going to be a stackoverflow iphone app?

(This can be built for stackexchange sites as well)

I know I would use it!

If it already exists let me know where to find it!

Comment: I never get these questions... Why can't you just enter the site?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Mobile and iPhone optimized version of Stack Overflow](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/896/mobile-and-iphone-optimized-version-of-stack-overflow)

Comment: https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/stacksearchq/id885989902?ls=1&mt=8

Answer (score 1):

http://itunes.apple.com/us/app/devcred/id356110207?mt=8

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for!

Comment: app crashes after launch on iPhone 4. Since it costs money to buy it this is pretty irritating.

Comment: $0.99 is too much to pay for a developers hard work?

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at [StackApps.com.](http://stackapps.com)  That is where there is discussion about the api.  I'm not sure off the top of my head if there is an iPhone app yet.  I do know that there is an Objective C library.

Looks like [this](https://stackapps.com/questions/623/six-to-eight-an-iphone-client) is one.

Comment: https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/stacksearchq/id885989902?ls=1&mt=8

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at [StackMobile](http://stackmobile.com).

It's optimized for iPod/iPhone.