# Mobile version of Stack Overflow

Tags: support, stack-overflow, mobile-web

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Mobile and iPhone optimized version of Stack Overflow](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/896/mobile-iphone-optimized-version-of-so)

Is there a Stack Overflow address for mobile? or a Stack Overflow application for mobile?

I love Stack Overflow and would like to browse, reply and ask questions from my mobile without the need to load the standard site, but with a lighter one (for example, `m.stackoverflow.com`).

Does any of this exist?

Comment: Should move to meta

Comment: @Grace, yup, my bad.

Comment: There is a blackberry client in developpement on stackapps.com there is also an iPhone and Android version.

Answer (score 3):

http://stackmobile.com/ is one

Answer (score 3):

Have a look at [StackMobile.com](http://stackmobile.com).  It is a read only mobile optimized version of the Stack Exchange sites built on the Stack Exchange API.