# Can markdown icons be available on the iPad?

Tags: feature-request, edits, editor

As you can see by the screenshot below, **neither buttons nor even the live-preview** is available on the iPad.

[image]

**StackExchange** is great on mobile devices, maybe it can be full available in mobile safari as well.

The same thing happens with the **tags autocomplete**, **there is no options for it**! we need to check previous questions to know what tags are available to use.

Comment: +1, but mainly for the tag-autocomplete part

Comment: if we forgot the code or simple want to add a screenshot (pic in Photos) the "add image" icon is a must :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not at the moment, the editor is not compatible with mobile safari. Sorry.

Comment: See: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/896/mobile-iphone-optimized-version-of-so/12564#12564

Comment: @Farseeker So because it affects a few people its disabled for everyone? Whats wrong with a "Turn off Editor" option?

Comment: @lord - it affects **everyone** on the iPhone/iPad. That's 100% of iP* users, hardly "a few people". As far as I know it's only disabled for mobile safari - not other mobile browsers.

Comment: **is there anything I can help?** I'm a web developer, and do some business web apps for iPhone and iPad. Is it the same with the Tag Autocomplete?

Comment: I'm wondering if simply disabling the auto-preview on mobile safari will bring it back to usable state