# Add markdown toolbar to mobile web

Tags: feature-request, markdown, mobile-web

On the full site, there's that helpful Markdown toolbar above the post box:
[image]

This is conspicuously missing in the mobile site:
[image]

It's difficult just to get a bracket on my iPad. Backticks aren't even available. If there's a view that really needs it, i vote mobile.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Can markdown icons be available on the iPad?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/62305/can-markdown-icons-be-available-on-the-ipad)

Comment: The editor is not compatible with mobile browsers, see linked dupe.

Comment: I've just realized that new users who are using Stack Exchange through mobile/smart phones would find it difficult to learn formatting text properly and they would be unable to apply this feature from mobile-web. (see [this comment](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/40170/verses-in-upanishads-and-vedas-to-remain-unaffected-by-bad-company/40184?noredirect=1#comment126506_40184) for example). So, I think if we want to see properly formatted and good quality posts from new users, providing this feature to mobile-web would be worthy.

Comment: @Pandya The Mobile view is being phased out, once Responsiveness is fully rolled out on all pages of the Main Site view. See https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/343182/334566