# The mobile version of the website does not display the amount of reputation gained on the reputation leagues

Tags: support, mobile-web, reputation-leagues

The [reputation leagues](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users) on the mobile version of the website are not displaying the amount of reputation gained on the selected period as normally shown on the desktop version, instead they are showing the total reputation attained by the user and their badges.

To illustrate I have attached screenshots below.

Here it displays the amount of reputation gained during the week.

[image: desktop]

Here it displays the amount of reputation attained and the user's badges.

[image: mobile]

Comment: The mobile views are no longer being maintained and are [actively being removed](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/343207/141525). Consider switching to the full view with responsiveness enabled, which does show the correct information.