# How do I change the website format?

Tags: support

I accidentally clicked something and now my website on Islam Stack Exchange looks like the PC version when I use a phone.

[image]

I want it like the image above but instead it is like the image below.

[image]

Comment: Just out of curiosity, is there something you don't like about the PC version? It's likely  that the PC version will replace the mobile version.

Comment: @KodosJohnson It could be that the responsive site [takes too long to load under slow Internet connections](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/343182/please-dont-completely-remove-the-mobile-website-for-the-benefit-of-users-on-s).