# Add banner to top of mobile site linking to responsive site

Tags: feature-request, mobile-web

## TL;DR: Add a banner to the top of the mobile site linking to the responsive site.

I regularly use the responsive site on my phone and occasionally, when I haven't been on a certain site for a while, or if I go onto a site I don't normally, I am presented with the mobile version of the site. It would be extremely helpful if a banner was added to the top of the mobile site linking to the responsive site.

Adding a banner to the top of the mobile site will encourage users who still use it to migrate to the responsive site, since the mobile site is being phased out. It will also allow users to switch to the responsive site quicker and easier; *this is especially useful for users who struggle to find the little link located at the bottom of the site*:

[image: Mobile link to full site]

---

**Here is an example banner:**

[image: mobile site]

Comment: I am not against the idea of some kind of easy mobile mode switching, it is a good idea but please, no more banners or pop ups, there must be a better way. The internet today is like those dodgy porn sits from the 90's with all the pop ups and banners. "since the mobile site is being phased out" Is this true? I couldn't find a post about it.

Comment: @MarkKirby Yes, it's true. See https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/343182/334566

Comment: I mostly use my phone to visit Stack Exchange these days. The responsive full site is nice for some sites, like MSE, but on most of my sites I generally prefer the mobile site, and only switch briefly to the full site for tasks that cannot be performed on the mobile site.