# Stack overflow mobile site

Tags: support, stack-overflow, mobile-web

IS there any mobile site that eases answering questions whilst I'm on the iPhone. It is quite difficult doing it on the iPhone with the regular site.

If not is there an API I can use to code my own version?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Mobile / iPhone Optimized Version of SO](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/896/mobile-iphone-optimized-version-of-so) (Though the API part of the question has other duplicates.)

Comment: @Arjan - the other question is marked as completed, while the problem still remains.

Comment: I'm visiting Stack Overflow from iPhone regulary. I have only two problems - reading code blocks (iPhone doesn't show scroll bars) and marking part of an answer as a code block.

Comment: @Pollyanna, I'm not sure I'm getting your point. Questions marked "solved" while not solving someone else's problem has never stopped questions from being closed as duplicates? That aside, it seems there are some apps mentioned in the answers at the other questions?

Comment: @Ladislav - you can still scroll the code blocks, even though there are no scroll bars - use two fingers within the block area.

Answer (score 1):

No, there is no mobile optimized stackoverflow site.

No, the [API](https://stackapps.com/) is currently read only.

If you wanted to pursue coding your own, I'd suggest writing a website wrapper in C#, Python, PHP, etc, hosting it on another website, where the wrapper would replace the default css with a custom version you design.

It isn't trivial due to the extent of the design of the site, but it may be your best bet.

Answer (score 1):

By chance I was looking for a mobile version and found this site (not affiliated) that provides a decent read-only view of Stackoverflow - http://stackoverflow.mobi/

There's also an Anroid app called [Droidstack](https://market.android.com/details?id=org.droidstack) that is available on the Market - but I've not tried it so can't comment.

Comment: Droidstack works great!! Test on my side and you can do almost the same as normaly with a computer. You can event chat!

Answer (score 1):

The (beta) mobile theme has been rolled out to all sites on Stack Exchange, you should be able to see it on your mobile devices.

See [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/98776/stack-exchange-mobile-launched).

Comment: Link is not working on my side...

Comment: @Simon: Link has been updated.

Comment: Thank you! Gotta try this on my Android :)

Answer (score 0):

Yes Stack Overflow exposes itself using the OData protocol.  There's a bunch of mobile apps on the Android market for it, I'm not sure about the iPhone app store.

Comment: Im not familiar with oData. Is this two way data? Or read only?

Comment: http://www.odata.org/  Google is magic... :)  But it's two-way, depending on permissions and so on.

Comment: I thought the OData support was only present on [the Data Explorer](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/12/re-launching-stack-exchange-data-explorer/)? (Which is currently [only updated](http://data.stackexchange.com/faq) shortly after every Stack Exchange Creative Commons Data Dump --which is kind of monthly-- and is read-only by design, @Andy.)