# Why is stackexchange.com lacking a mobile website?

Tags: discussion, stackexchange.com, mobile-web

I'm wondering why stackexchange.com doesn't have a mobile website, because I've noticed that stackoverflow, webapps, askubuntu (and more) have one.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I'm sure it's just a matter of they haven't gotten around to it yet. The mobile versions of the Q&A sites [just rolled out recently](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/98776/stack-exchange-mobile-launched). I imagine the portal site is lower priority since it only serves secondary issues, it isn't the core of the network.